# Possible to echo the result of an AT command through router?

Tags: linux, at-command, tty

So I am trying to capture the result of an AT command that is sent to a module through a router.

So far, I can get something if I open two telnet sessions into the router.

On one telnet session, I access the output of ttyUSB2 using

```
cat /dev/ttyUSB2 | more
```

On the second terminal, I send commands using

```
echo -e "AT+ICCID\r\n" > /dev/ttyUSB2
```

This command returns the serial number of the sim within the router. 
The command works, and I can see the result in the output terminal, but the terminal is on some sort of loop

```
+COPS: 0,0,"Verizon Wireless",7

OK

+CSQ: 24,99

OK

+COPS: 0,0,"Verizon Wireless",7

OK

+CSQ: 24,99

OK

+COPS: 0,0,"Verizon Wireless",7

OK

+CSQ: 24,99

OK

+COPS: 0,0,"Verizon Wireless",7

OK
```

where it fires off two commands automatically. Once the loop terminates, the router has to try and find the sim again, so I have to "q" out immediately after getting my result or I lose connection.

Is there a way to read ttyUSB2 AND fire off AT commands AND echo a result all in the same command line? The idea is to capture the result and do something with it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to do exactly this with my [atinout](http://atinout.sourceforge.net/) program:

```
$ echo AT+ICCID | atinout - /dev/ttyUSB2 captured_result.txt
```

Comment: That looks great. I also put this together:``cat /dev/ttyUSB2` echo -e "AT+ICCID\r\n" > /dev/ttyUSB2`   <---This works, but is there a termination command that I can include in this so that it ONLY captures the ICCID, which is the very first line in the return? In the mean time, I will try the method that you presented.